# Simple C++ Program Crash before main is called

Tags: c++, debugging, clang++

I am beginning the coding again but I am stumbling at running this code in FreeBSD 11 release. The code crashes with segmentation fault error.

```
#include <iostream>


int is_array_sorted(int a[], int n)
{
if(n==2 || n==1)
    return 1;
else if(a[n-1]<a[n-2])
    return 0;
is_array_sorted(a,n-1);
}

int main()
{
int a[] = {1,2,3,4} ;
int ret = is_array_sorted(a,4);

std::cout<<"sorted ->"<< ret <<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

So, I build this using

```
 c++ file.cpp --std=c++14 -g3
```

ran and it crashed.

Also, I thought to debug using gdb by setting breakpoint at main symbol. However, it crashes even then giving "Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Illegal instruction.
The program no longer exists.

Please help out in figuring what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The final statement in `is_array_sorted` doesn't return anything -> undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `is_array_sorted` function is prototyped to return an `int` so that is what it must do in all code paths<sup>(a)</sup>.

Yours does so when `n` is one or two, or when the two elements being examined are out of order, but *not* when they're in order.

In that case, it drops through to the final statement, and *doesn't* return an `int` - that's the most likely cause as to what's crashing the code.

Change that final line to:

```
return is_array_sorted (a, n-1);
```

and try again.

As an aside, I'm not really that big a fan of the `if ... return else ...` school of programming since it unnecessarily complicates the code structure.

You also appear to have an incorrect case in your logic, returning "true" when `n` is equal to two. Passing the array `{5, 4}`, with an `n` of two, should show you why that's a bad idea.

A better approach fixing both those issues, in my opinion, would be something like:

```
int is_array_sorted (int a[], int n) {
    if (n==1)
        return 1;
    if (a[n-1] < a[n-2])
        return 0;
    return is_array_sorted (a, n-1);
}
```

(but, even if you disregard my layout advice, you should still fix the `n == 2` issue).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> As per `C++11 6.6.3 The return statement /2`:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I need to revise the basics :(

Comment: Still strange that the debugger would not even get to the start of the `main` function, before `is_array_sorted` is even called. There are no static global objects or anything otherwise suspicious in the OP's code. Why does GCC even produce a binary like this?

Comment: @Christian, that's the thing about undefined behaviour, the standard places no limits on what may happen. It's totally valid for the implementation to format your disks and play an AVI file of someone laughing derisively :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Or just produce a binary which crashes when the broken function is called. I don't think GCC usually doesn't even let the debugger arrive at `main` just because there's one instance of UB somewhere in your entire program. Perhaps in this case it's because `main` itself calls the broken function.